# CodeIgniter uploads files with duplicate file extensions

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Any obvious reasons why CodeIgniter would duplicate the file extension when using its Upload library? Tried all sort of ways to set the file name (with and without extension) and nothing seem to work. Any tips?

Comment: A link I hope can help you http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/169850/#809842

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this same issue previously (unsure why, as it certainly doesn't occur in all my projects). The following fixed it for me (where $file_name is name of file):

```
$ext = end(explode('.',$file_name)); 
$config['file_name'] = basename($file_name,'.'.$ext);
```